# Allow users to create posts without logging in?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, functions, customization

I am working on a site where users can share their story.
Every story is a blog post.

I don't want that they mail me the story and I publish them, I want to provide them a form where they provide the title & content, and their story gets posted immediately when they click **submit**.

Comment: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-post-frontend-plugins/

Comment: So you want anonymous posts? https://wordpress.org/plugins/accesspress-anonymous-post/

Comment: I've had clients ask if that can be done. As Bondye said, there are ways to do that. I think that might be possible with Formidable Pro, too. Just remember: this may be an open invitation for spam, profanity, and other fun!

Comment: use this plugin .. it allows guests to post without needing to login [Guest Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/guest-posts/)

Answer (score 0):

What you could use to prevent bots filling your site with SPAM:

[Post to your blog using email](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email)

This functionality used to be in the Core but has since been **deprecated**.

You can use [Post By Email Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-by-email/) but that hasn't been update since 9 years ago.

Or, you can use [Post by Mail in Jetpack](https://jetpack.com/support/post-by-email/). Is up to date and maintained by Autommatic (the WordPress guys)

And, you can use [Postie Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postie/)
.

All of these can be found in linked article above.